# Is a compact Kähler manifold $X$ with $c_1(X)<0$ projective?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

As the famous Kodaira's embedding theorem states:

> A compact Kähler manifold $X$ is a projective manifold if and only if there a positive line bundle $L$ of $X$.

So, my question is if $X$ admits a negative line bundle, is $X$ still projective?

Particularly, if the first Chern class $c_1(X)$ is negative, is it still projective? I doubt the answer may be yes because by the proof in Morrow and Kodaira's book, the authors choose a Kähler form $\omega$ equals to a positive element of $c_1(X)\in H^{1,1}(X,\mathbb Z)$, so if $c_1(X)$ is negative, we may choose $\omega=-c_1(X)$ thus get a Hodge metric, so we proved that $X$ with a negative first Chern class is also projective, is that right? Any comments are welcome!

Comment: If $X$ has a negative line bundle $\mathcal{L}$, then isn’t $\mathcal{L}^{-1}$ positive?

Comment: @Mindlack maybe this is the answer I needed.